# Azure Application Gateway overriding X-Forwarded-Proto

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

In Azure, I have a web app running in a VM that receives http traffic through Application Gateway.

The clients of this app (other apps) need to send the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header in the requests.

The problem is that although the client is sending `X-Forwarded-Proto = https`, the app receives `X-Forwarded-Proto = http`. Not only the app is showing this, but IIS logs show the same thing.

My theory is that as the request to this app was through http, Application Gateway is overriding the header to http. However I need Application Gateway to preserve the value that the client sent (if it was sent). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Kindly check this refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-http-to-https-portal

Comment: I checked it, unfortunately I think the problem is that AppGW is not using the `X-Forwarded-Proto` value that the client passed and uses it's own. Might be a security thing as this is a standard header.